# Possible to suck water through manual bilge pump using a transfer pump?

Tags: pressure, pumps, vacuum-pumps

I dug a shallow well (12' deep) on a remote off-grid Florida Property I own.  The well  is a simple 1-1/4 PVC Sand Point well I hammered in the ground.  I then used a rubber coupler to attach a cheap manual bilge pump.  The pump works surprisingly well filling a home depot bucket with just a few strokes.  However, my choice for the well location was about finding some out of the way low laying spot rather than convenience. I hit water on the first try.

My van has an onboard 12v transfer pump that claims it can pull water 40' up and an 8 gallon tank on the roof I want to fill. I am able to drive the van about 20' from the well, but my transfer pump says the line must be primed.  I have a 25' 3/8 recoiled hose and I can fit a garden end on the output of  the manual bilge pump. I suspect I will have no issue priming the line with the bilge pump, BUT,  I am wondering if I would be ***ABLE TO SUCK WATER WITH THE TRANSFER PUMP THROUGH THE BILGE PUMP?***

Understanding the design of these pumps they are basically two one way check valves that should allow for water to move freely upward while maintaining prime. I'm just not sure if an external suction source will be able to do that THROUGH the manual pump and how much added pressure this will put on the electric transfer pump which sounds very powerful but is 20' away.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible if the pump exceeds the losses in the system.

Comment: Thanks, but concern is only with capacity, not my misunderstanding about how these valves in the bilge pump work?  I was just wondering if an external source can suck THROUGH the Bilge pump.  I am planning to reduce the hose size to only 3/8 ID vs a standard hose so think I'm well within rating, but the well head is 1-1/4 wide x 12' deep.  My plan is to always prime the line manually.

Comment: 40' up means lifting water 12m? IMO that can't be right.

Comment: Basically your are asking us to estimate the hydraulic resistance of your bilge pump (Your understanding of the situation is quite correct IMO). Even with more information on the pump we likely can't do that. My *guess* would be that your transfer pump would fail.

Comment: update: even though the pump was able to pull water from a garbage can when a 50 foot 3/8 hose was inserted into the garbage can, the pump was unable to pull water from the 12' x 1-1/4 inch shallow well.  To be clear my van is 50' away from the pump head, the shallow well is only 12' deep.